# Proving a convergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It is given that
$$x_1>0$$

$$x_{n+1}=x_n  +  \frac{n^2}{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}$$

How do I prove that $(x_n/n)$ is convergent?

Comment: Proving the convergence of a recursive series like this one is usually easiest using the  d'Alambert criterion [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test]

Comment: As $(x_n)$ is increasing, $x_n\ge x_1$, so $\frac{x_n}{n}\ge \frac{x_1}{n}$ which leads to a divergent series. So do you mean the **series** $\sum\frac{x_n}{n}$, or the **sequence** $\left(\frac{x_n}{n}\right)$ ?

Comment: By Cesaro-Stoltz, assuming the mentioned limits exist, $$L=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{x_n}{n} = \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{1}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n^2}{x_1+\ldots+x_n}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2n+1}{x_{n+1}}$$

Comment: From which $L=\color{red}{\sqrt{2}}$. Now you just have to prove that the mentioned limits really exist.